# How to revert back application icon after changing the installation folder's name?

Tags: windows, icons

I'm going to try to explain this as good as I can. I have installed a couple of IDEs on D:\ but I had to change the installation folder's name after they were already installed (From 'apps' to 'IDEs', minor stuff). But ever since I changed them, the programs actual icons (the thumbnails) all look like the default windows thumbnail for unrecognized programs.
[Here's what they look like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lja2O.png) I'm talking about the Jetbrains IDEs like PyCharm, DataGrip etc. [Originally they looked like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGeWE.png) I know this is a minor problem but me and my OCD is wondering just out of curiosity if this can be reverted without actually uninstalling and reinstalling them.

Comment: Check `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" -v DisplayIcon -s` (launch in an open `cmd` window), maybe `reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall" -v DisplayIcon -s`, maybe `HKCU` instead of `HKLM` as well…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some programs are registering the path to icons using environment variables. Make sure your environment variables are updated to the new path and not the previous path.
Open settings to check this environment.

Look at the shortcut file properties: this is where you'll find the path to the icon: if there are variables like "%TOOL%", search for the "TOOL" environment variable in your windows session settings (which may have not been updated for your current user, if you change the installation from another user).

Look also your registry in HKCU\software and HKLM\software for your software name and search for the old path, your installed software is probably incorrectly registered still with the old path.

You may also want to just reinstall these apps and be more careful about the installation path instead of reusing the default proposed path in a subfolder of "C:\Programs" or "C:\Programs (x86)\".

Reinstallation will fix the registration and is generally faster and safer than tweaking the registry manually.

Note: Windows is not MacOS, you cannot safely "move" an application from one drive to another by simple drag and drop of folder with the File explorer. So select the target path correctly in the application installer.

Answer (score 0):

The software has moved, but the shortcuts still point to the old location.
To fix:

- Right-click each icon and choose *Properties*
- Go to the *Shortcut* tab
- Click the button "Change Icon ..."
- Change at the beginning of the string "C:" to "D:" (if required).
  If that's not enough, click the "Browse ..." button and find the executable.
- The right icon should be displayed (perhaps with other icons)
- Click on the icon
- Click OK.